# react-router browserHistory doesn't work on Apache server

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, react-router

I have an HTML single page app that I'm trying to get working with react router's browserHistory, but with no success. Everything works fine on local dev server and also in prod when using hashHistory.

Things I have tried from everything I've read so far:

- .htaccess update from the official docs (this doesn't seem to do anything). Can anyone confirm that this works?
- createBrowserHistory (with and without webpack plugin)

Is that a known limitation for Apache servers? Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution for this. I changed path and links to include './'. I had to do the same for `bundle.js` script. Not sure if this is something uniq to Apache server, but browserHistory works fine for me now.

You also don't need to add any .htaccess configs for this to work this way.

I'll note that I had my test folder not in the root folder on the server, maybe this is important.

Working example code for Router

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="./" component={Intro}/>
    <Route path="./news" component={News}/>
    <Route path="./about" component={About}/>
</Router>
```

and Links

```
<Link to="./">Intro</Link>
<Link to="./news">News</Link>
<Link to="./about">About</Link>
```

If someone could explain why this could be necessary or have a different fix, would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I tried it like this but it did not help me. What fixed it for me was adding the following to the apache directives:
Options +FollowSymLinks

Comment: Thanks, I can try that. I found out that it works fine (as document in Router docs) if the files are in the root directory, so I keep them there (no need for subfolder right now).

When you use FollowSymLinks, do you keep paths with or without a period?

Comment: I use paths with periods.